# Как добавить тень для такого SVG?

Tags: svg

Добрый день, импортирую svg из Adobe Illustrator. Изображение стрелки имеет такой код.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   width="30.728px" height="40.728px" viewBox="0 0 12.728 22.728" enable-background="new 0 0 12.728 22.728" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#c1c1c1" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M12.728,11.414L1.414,22.728L0,21.314l9.95-9.95L0,1.414L1.414,0l11.314,11.314
  l-0.05,0.05L12.728,11.414z"/>
</svg>
```

Подскажите как тут добавить тень.

Так выглядит фигура:

> [image]

Comment: Конечно, спасибо вам, я уже и забыл)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Вариант с использованием двойной стрелки и применением размытия тени.**

- В качестве тени выступает вторая стрелка, которая находится под
  первой и сдвигается относительно первой вниз и влево с помощью
  команды SVG

  `transform="translate(-0.5 2.5)"`
- Размытие тени с помощью фильтра Гаусса

  `<filter id="shadow" height="120%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1"/>`
- Раз автор выбрал SVG, то изображение лучше сделать  масштабируемым
  для этого viewport в процентах

  `width="25%" height="25%"`

Можно легко изменить размеры стрелки, меняя проценты, но при этом стрелка всегда будет масштабируемой.

```html
<svg width="25%" height="25%" viewBox="0 0 30 40"> 
<defs>
  <filter id="shadow" height="120%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1"/>
  </filter>
</defs>
  <polyline transform="translate(-0.5 2.5)" filter="url(#shadow)" points="5,5 25,20 5,35" stroke="grey" stroke-width="1" fill="none"/>
  <polyline points="5,5 25,20 5,35" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2" fill="none"  />
</svg>
```

Comment: Alexandr_TT, ты тут?

Comment: @Air Привет, если есть вопрос в чат зайди

Answer (score 5):

В SVG можно добавить тень с помощью SVG-фильтров:

Сначала опишем фильтр в специальном разделе defs:

```
  <defs>
      //начало описания фильтра
    <filter id="myfilter" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
      // Взять прозрачность объекта и сместить на 2px вниз и вправо
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="2" dy="2" />
      // Затем размыть силой 2
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="2" />
      //  и совместить с исходным изображением:
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
```

Затем у объекта укажем, что мы хотим использовать этот фильтр:

```
<path .... filter="url(#myfilter)" .... />
```

Фильтр будет обрезан по краю SVG. Поэтому я добавил немного поля снизу и справа:

```
<svg ... viewBox="0 0 18 30">
```

```html
<svg width="35" viewBox="0 0 18 30">
  <defs>
    <filter id="myfilter" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="2" dy="2" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="2" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
<path fill="#c1c1c1" fill-rule="evenodd" filter="url(#myfilter)" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M12.728,11.414L1.414,22.728L0,21.314l9.95-9.95L0,1.414L1.414,0l11.314,11.314
  l-0.05,0.05L12.728,11.414z"/>
</svg>
```